# The answer doesn't meet the constraints

Tags: opl

I'm applying a MILP about vehicle routing in opl. 
One important constraint is that, each trip can be served at maximum once by one vehicle. (each trip has a profit for serving it)
So I'd like opl to maximize total profit and show me which trips are served.
However, the result shows that certain trips are served by all the vehicles.
So I think there are something wrong about the code.

I've tried different ways to write my constraints, (eg. remove "k in K" from "for all" bracket), but the results are the same.

[Model file]

{int}J=...; // trip request

{int}K=...; // Car

/* parameters */

float Pj[J]=...; // profit earned by fullfilling modified rental request j

/* Expression of Desicion Variables */
dexpr float profit = sum(j in J, k in K) Pj[j]*x[j][k];

/*Objective function*/

maximize profit;

/*constraints*/

constraint ct1 [J][K];

subject to {

```
forall (j in J, k in K)
  ct1 [j][k]: sum(i in J) x[i][k] <= 1;
```

}

```
        // end subject to.
```

/* +++ PRINT OUTPUT +++ PRINT OUTPUT +++ PRINT OUTPUT +++ */

execute printOutput{
    writeln();

```
write("profit= ", profit);

 writeln();     //number of trips j served 
write("number of trips served = ")
for (var j in J){
     for(var k in K){
            write( x[j][k], "\t")   
            }   

        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the constraint ct1 is relaxed since it is soft.
CPLEX will relax soft constraints if needed

If you turn

```
ct1 [j][k]: sum(i in J) x[i][k] <= 1;
```

into

```
sum(i in J) x[i][k] <= 1;
```

then the constraint will get hard.